# what's the best place to setup/create a CLLocationManager?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I've been reading quite a bit about problems with region monitoring - a search for "region monitoring not working" returns 117 questions.

The more that I learn about it, the more I think that the setting up and creation of the CLLocationManager is key.  And probably where I'm having my trouble - I get seemingly random (and rare) firings of didEnterRegion.

So for those of you who have great experience with region monitoring, how do you deal with your CLLocationManager?  Where is it created?  Is it a singleton?